# How can I use mongoimport on a python container to upload a file to a mongodb on another container

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-network, mongoimport

I am looking into how to use `mongoimport` on my container running a python program to send a file on that python container over to another container on the same docker network.Currently I am using the following command to try to do this:

```
mongoimport --host mongo --port 27017 --db vulns --collection qualys-kb --file kb.json --jsonArray
```

In the above command, I am trying to connect to the container called `mongo`, which is on the same docker network as the container that is running this command. `mongo` is currently running mongodb and is accessible through the standard 27017 port. Yet when I try to run the above command I get the following error:

```
2023-09-21T12:39:09.184+0000    error connecting to host: failed to connect to mongodb://mongo:27017/: server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Single, Servers: [{ Addr: mongo:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occurred during connection handshake: dial tcp: lookup mongo on 192.168.1.1:53: no such host }, ] }
```

Can anyone offer any advice on how to get this working so that I can reference the mongo container by name in the `mongoimport` command. If there is a different approach to do the same thing I would be open to that too.

Comment: Can you `ping` between the containers using the container names?

Comment: @rickhg12hs - I am able to see the IP addresses of the container, and I am able to ping when I try to ping the IP address, but I am not able to ping when I try to use the hostname. Meaning `ping 172.0.0.2` works, but `ping mongo` does not.

Comment: Are both containers attached to the same [user-defined bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/drivers/bridge/)?

Comment: I see that you are not able to ping by name since the DNS does not work in the networks that are created by default, you have to create your own custom bridge network